# ms-access audit trail not working and producing errors. Invalid number of arguments

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

```
Public Function AuditChanges(RecordID As String, UserAction As String)
On Error GoTo auditerr

Dim DB As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim clt As Control
Dim UserLogin As String

Set DB = CurrentDb
Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset("select * from tbl_AuditTrail", adOpenDynamic)

UserLogin = Environ("UserName")
Select Case UserAction
    Case "New"
        With rst
            .AddNew
            ![DateTime] = Now()
            !UserName = UserLogin
            !FormName = ScreenActiveForm.Name
            !Action = UserAction
            !RecordID = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(RecordID).Value
            .Update
        
        End With
        
    Case "Delete"
        With rst
            .AddNew
            ![DateTime] = Now()
            !UserName = UserLogin
            !FormName = ScreenActiveForm.Name
            !Action = UserAction
            !RecordID = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(RecordID).Value
            .Update
    End With
        
    Case "Edit"
        For Each clt In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
            If (clt.ControlType = acTextBox _
                Or clt.ControlType = acComboBox) Then
                If Nz(clt.Value) <> Nz(clt.OldValue) Then
                      With rst
                        .AddNew
                        ![DateTime] = Now()
                        !UserName = UserLogin
                        !FormName = ScreenActiveForm.Name
                        !Action = UserAction
                        !RecordID = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(RecordID).Value
                        !FieldName = clt.ControlSource
                        !OldValue = clt.OldValue
                        !newvalue = clt.Value
                        .Update
                      End With
                    End If
                End If
        Next clt
End Select

rst.Close
DB.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set DB = Nothing

auditerr:
    MsgBox Err.LastDllError & " : " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please [edit] and improve your question. Also explain in which line of code the error occurs.

Comment: The objective is to record all changes to information on a form and place it into tbl_AuditTrail. I tried debugging but its not showing me where the problem is. I tried copying and pasting the code but the site is not allowing it hence i copied and pasted. Let me try copying and pasting it again.

Comment: Please read [ask], your post has no proper description of the error nor what you tried to fix it. Also you need to ask a question that we can answer. Note that [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) at all. Please also describe how you run this function `AuditChanges`.

Comment: Understood. My apologies I’m new on this platform and I’m rather stressed about this issue. If I may be allowed to ask it here? After creating the module and calling it in the “Before Update” field on my form I receive errors. Namely 3001 invalid number of arguments. I have tried debugging but it’s not showing me where the problem is in the code.

Comment: One problem I can see which may or may not be related to your problem - your error handlers is in the main body of code.  Even if everything executes perfectly it will still get to the `MsgBox Err.LastDllError & " : " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"` line.  Place `Exit Function` before the `auditerr:` line.  Then use a `Resume` to jump back in to the code - jump back to a place that tidies variables up before exiting if need be.

Comment: No worries that's why I tried to help making this a question that we can answer. Can you show the `Before Update` code?

Comment: You can use the `Edit` button (just below the tags) to add extra info to your question, rather than putting it in as a comment.

Comment: I called the function using =AuditChanges()

Comment: Thank you tremendously Darren. I will definitely try this and get back to you in a bit

Comment: This site looks ok for an error handling explanation:  https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/

Comment: You cannot call the function `=AuditChanges()` since it expects the `RecordID` and `UserAction` arguments.

Answer (score 2):

If you called your function like `=AuditChanges()` it is clear that it cannot work because the function expects exactly 2 arguments according how it is defined:

```
Public Function AuditChanges(RecordID As String, UserAction As String)
```

And that is why you get the error

> Invalid number of arguments.

The function needs `2` arguments (`RecordID` and `UserAction`) and you sumbittet `0`.

So you need to submit the `RecordID` and the `UserAction`. For example:

```
=AuditChanges("YourRecordIDControlName", "New")
```